I want to send a amp email upon which on uses's interaction i can update a amp-list
 <amp-list>
<template type="amp-mustache">
some data
data 1 
data 2
data 3
</template>
</amp-list>

buttons
button 1 
button 2
button 3


now when i click on button below what i want is that above list should get reloaded.
like a refresh.
I tried various approach like i added the buttons in the form and then tried to use amp submot-sucess but its not working out.

See example here:
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/email/amp-list#refreshing-data
tl;dr: add a tap event listener on a button to trigger the refresh action on an amp-list.

Thanks Alot , I read the link above and now it works.
